# JS counter with adding spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, counting

I have this code:

```
function startCounter(){
$('.counter').each(function (index) {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
   }    
   startCounter();
```

and `<span class="counter">15000</span>`

I want to combine it with

```
 num.toLocaleString() ;
```

to show for example 15 000 instead of 15000

I am not expert at javascript, so I don't know how to do it. Can somebody help, please?

Comment: This question is not very expressive.  What are you trying to do in a more abstract question?

Comment: post the code in the question, not a fiddle

Comment: When it is counting, I want to show higher numbers with space (10 000 instead of 10000).

Comment: `$(this).text(now.toLocaleString('en-US'));`, check the corresponding function [for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve] then edit the question with a properly detailed problem description and include the relevant code in the question itself

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create another helper-function, that takes a number as an input and gives you the localized string back. Then you can wrap the part of your code with it, that gives you the actual number (`Math.ceil(now)`).
The combination of the two for arabic (just an example) would look like this:

```
function startCounter(){
    $('.counter').each(function (index) {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(toArabic(Math.ceil(now)));
        }
        });
    });
}   

function toArabic(x) {
    return x.toLocaleString('ar-EG');
}

startCounter();
```

To get your specific country-code, just look up "BCP 47 language tag".
Hope I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with help of KofferDev, I got it working:

```
   $('.count').each(function () {
   $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
       Counter: $(this).text()
   }, {
       duration: 2000,
       easing: 'swing',
       step: function (now) {
           $(this).text(toArabic(Math.ceil(now)));
       }
   });
 });

 function toArabic(x) {
     return x.toLocaleString('cs-CZ');
 }
```

And HTML part is same:

`<span class="counter">15000</span>`